# Vue JS 2: Изменение binding.value в custom directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Интересует возможность изменения входящего параметра в дериктиве.

Пример не рабочего кода:

Шаблон:

```
<div v-my-directive="poss.y"></div>
```

Дериктива:

```
Vue.directive('my-directive', {
    twoWay: true,
    update: function(el, binding) {
        binding.value = el.scrollHeight;
    }
});
```

Много информации пересмотрел, конкретного решения не нашел. Изменять через HTMLElement.dataset не возможно, v-bind на пользовательском аттрибуте не работает. В официальной документации binding следует понимать как только для чтения и никогда не изменять его. У Evan You на github был пример решения подобной проблемы, но репозиторий был удален.

Данную дериктиву использую в компонентах, через $vm0 напрямую изменять нет возможности.

Есть ли сбособ изменить значение binding.value в самой дериктиве, не прибегая к артрибутам тега?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я понял, вы хотите изменить значение передаваемого в директиву аргумента, причем не просто изменить его внутри директивы, а у компонента в котором создана дитектива. Если так то рекомендую вам обратиться к атрибуту vnode метода bind

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#VNode-Interface

Его свойство context - и есть ссылка на компонент в котором создана директива.

```
Vue.directive('my-directive', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        vnode.context.poss.y = 7;
    }
});
```

Вот [фиддл](https://jsfiddle.net/6tmzwm1r/) - при создании свойство poss.y имеет значение "2", при создании директивы оно обновляется на "7", проверить это можно нажав на элемент.